# How can I to detect if keyboard is attached?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have a MFC Application that sometime work on touch screen
I want to open my virtual keyboard when focused edit box if keyboard isn't attached

Comment: Doesn't Windows 10 do this for you automatically? I'd guess [GetRawInputDeviceList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645598.aspx) though.

Comment: can pleas you to write complete code  as an answer? because I try it and not sussed

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). It's asking about your solution rather than the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick attempt at using [GetRawInputDeviceList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645598.aspx) to check for presence of a RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD device. I've skimped on the error handling though but hopefully it's obvious where it needs it. This does detect me removing my USB keyboard.

```
bool detectKeyboard() {
    bool bHasKeyboard = false;
    UINT nDevices;
    UINT ret = GetRawInputDeviceList(NULL, &nDevices, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));
    if (ret == 0) {
        PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST pRawInputDeviceList = new RAWINPUTDEVICELIST[nDevices];
        ret = GetRawInputDeviceList(pRawInputDeviceList, &nDevices,
                                    sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));

        if (ret != (UINT)-1) {
            for (UINT i = 0; i < nDevices; ++i) {
                if (pRawInputDeviceList[i].dwType == RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD) {
                    bHasKeyboard = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // else error calling GetRawInputDeviceList to fetch the devices list

        delete[] pRawInputDeviceList;
    }
    // else error calling GetRawInputDeviceList to return number of devices

    return bHasKeyboard;
}
```

(And it's been a while since I wrote C++ or MFC so apologies for any poor style.)